# Bash substring removal

Tags: json, regex, bash, substring

I have strings in the following pattern: `<SOMETHING_1>{<JSON>}<SOMETHING_2>`

I want to keep the `<JSON>` and remove the `<SOMETHING_X>`blocks. I'm trying to do it with substring removal, but instead of getting

```
{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}
```

I keep getting

```
{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some}
```

because the whitespace in the description field cuts off the substring.

Any ideas on what to change?

CODE:

```
string="000{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}401"
string=$1
string=$(echo "${string#*{}")
string=$(echo "${string%}*}")
string={$string}
echo $string
```

Comment: Does your JSON have any hashes `{...}` inside?

Comment: I'm not getting the output you showed. How do you pass the argument to the script?

Comment: Regardless of correctness, the performance overhead of subshells for the command substitutions is a bit unfortunate.

Comment: BTW, I suspect rather strongly that the value is actually getting cut off somewhere else -- for instance, if you're passing it into `$1` by invoking `yourscript $somevar` that would cause the problem, on account of needing to be `yourscript "$somevar"`; everything after the space is going into `$2` or a subsequent argument.

Comment: What's the `string=$1` line for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code works perfectly, if we accept a direct assignment of the string -- though the following is a bit more explicit:

```
string="000{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}401"
string='{'"${string#*"{"}"  # trim content up to and including the first {, and replace it
string="${string%'}'*}"'}'  # trim the last } and all after, and replace it again
printf '%s\n' "$string"
```

...properly emits:

```
{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}
```

I'm guessing that the string is being passed on a command line unquoted, and is thus being split into multiple arguments. If you quote your command-line arguments to prevent string-splitting by the calling shell (`./yourscript "$string"` instead of `./yourscript $string`), this issue will be avoided.

Comment: You were right in your comments above. It was the `$1` that was causing it to get cut off. Thanks a ton! Please add that to your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

with sed:

```
string="000{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}401"
sed 's/.*\({.*}\).*/\1/g' <<<$string
```

output:

```
{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here you go…

```
string="000{x:1,action:PLAYING,name:John,description:Some description rSxv9HiATMuQ4wgoV2CGxw}401"
echo "original: ${string}"
string="${string#*\{}"
string="${string%\}*}"
echo "final: {${string}}"
```

By the way, JSON keys should be surrounded with double quotes.